# QT QSystemTrayIcon on mac is squashed in the second screen

Tags: macos, qt

I create a system tray icon on MacBook. And I connect a screen with Mac. When I run this program,the system tran icon on the monitor is squashed.

```
 QSystemTrayIcon *m_tTrayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
 m_tTrayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("/Users/xxx/Downloads/pic.png")));
 m_tTrayIcon->show();
```

[image]
when the monitor is not focused, the icon is squashed.

[image]
and when I click the desktop of the monitor, the monitor is focused, the icon is also become normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Qt with new verisons of MacOS. Check out [this bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88600).

Solution would be either use fixed versions (they claim to fix it in 5.12.11 and 6.1.0) or compile cocoa plugin by your own and ship it with your application instead of one provided by Qt.

Fix is just a one line of code that you need to apply. The easiest way is:

1. download qtbase (for example from [github](https://github.com/qt/qtbase)) and checkout version you need
2. In case you will use Qt < 6.0.0 (i.e. building with qmake rather than with CMake) - copy `.qmake.conf` from root to `qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/`
3. you go to `qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa` and open `cocoa.pro` or `CMakeLists.txt` (depends on what version of Qt you have checked out)
4. you apply [patch](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/322339/3/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa/qcocoasystemtrayicon.mm) and compile the plugin

From now on you should use cocoa plugin you have just compiled instead of one shipped with Qt (either replace it in Qt installation or every time you deploy your application)